# Newbie Moose, MooseX::Storage, and MooseX::Log4Perl problem: Can't store object

Tags: perl, moose, moosex-types

I'm writing my first moose base program.  The program creates a "state" object that is a composition of several other moose objects.  At the end of the program, I wish to save the "state" object to a file.  I'm attempting to use MooseX::Storage to do this.  I get an error (below) that implies to me that it is trying to serialize the MooseX::Log::Log4perl object.

```
Object (Log::Log4perl::Logger=HASH(0x2211c800)) does not have a &pack method, cannot collapse at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/MooseX/Storage/Engine.pm line 205
    MooseX::Storage::Engine::__ANON__('Log::Log4perl::Logger=HASH(0x2211c800)', 'HASH(0x20c54890)') called at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/MooseX/Storage/Engine.pm line 88
MooseX::Storage::Engine::collapse_attribute_value('MooseX::Storage::Engine=HASH(0x2211cac0)', 'Moose::Meta::Attribute=HASH(0x20419510)', 'HASH(0x20c54890)') called at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/MooseX/Storage/Engine.pm line 60
MooseX::Storage::Engine::collapse_attribute('MooseX::Storage::Engine=HASH(0x2211cac0)', 'Moose::Meta::Attribute=HASH(0x20419510)', 'HASH(0x20c54890)') called at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/MooseX/Storage/Engine.pm line 141
MooseX::Storage::Engine::map_attributes('MooseX::Storage::Engine=HASH(0x2211cac0)', 'collapse_attribute', 'HASH(0x20c54890)') called at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/MooseX/Storage/Engine.pm line 37
MooseX::Storage::Engine::collapse_object('MooseX::Storage::Engine=HASH(0x2211cac0)') called at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/MooseX/Storage/Basic.pm line 13
MooseX::Storage::Basic::pack('ScanCtr::State=HASH(0x2100ee40)') called at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/MooseX/Storage/Format/JSON.pm line 24
MooseX::Storage::Format::JSON::freeze('ScanCtr::State=HASH(0x2100ee40)') called at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/MooseX/Storage/IO/File.pm line 19
```

Here's my setup.  I have a class called "ScanCtr::ScanMe" and it does only this:

```
package ScanCtr::ScanMe;
use Moose;
with 'MooseX::Log::Log4perl';
use namespace::autoclean;
use Log::Log4perl qw(:easy);
BEGIN {
    Log::Log4perl->easy_init({
        level   => $DEBUG,
        file    => ">>/var/log/sc.log",
        layout  => '%d %p [%P] %l %m%n',
    });
};
1;
```

My other objects including extend this object (which may be my problem) so I can do stuff like `$self->log->debug("debug message");` within each of my objects.  For example:

```
package ScanCtr::State;
use ScanCtr::Request;
use Moose;
extends 'ScanCtr::ScanMe';
use Moose::Util::TypeConstraints;
use MooseX::Storage;
our $VERSION = '0.01';
with Storage ( 'format' => 'JSON', 'io' => 'File');
use namespace::autoclean;


has 'requests'          => (
    traits  => [ 'Hash' ],
    is      => 'rw',
    isa     => 'HashRef[ScanCtr::Request]',
    default => sub { {} },
    handles => {
        count           => 'count',
        get             => 'get',
        set             => 'set',
        delete_request  => 'delete',
        request_keys    => 'keys',
        kv              => 'kv',
    }
);
1;
```

So is there a way to exclude the MooseX::Log::Log4perl from the Storage?  Is there a better approach that will avoid this problem?  What other newbie mistakes am I making?

Thanks for any help,
Todd.

Comment: Your perl version is ancient. Maybe unrelated to your problem but catches the eye.

Comment: Yes it is.  I'm locked in by idiotic corporate systems administration policies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *should* work (but I haven't tested it). Inside `ScanCtr::ScanMe` you need to override the Logger attribute and apply the `DoNotSerialize` trait from `MooseX::Storage`.

```
package ScanCtr::ScanMe;
use Moose;
with 'MooseX::Log::Log4perl';
use namespace::autoclean;
use Log::Log4perl qw(:easy);
BEGIN {
    Log::Log4perl->easy_init({
        level   => $DEBUG,
        file    => ">>/var/log/sc.log",
        layout  => '%d %p [%P] %l %m%n',
    });
};

has '+logger' => { traits => ['DoNotSerialize'] };

1;
```